# Get value from node with same name

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing, xmlnode

I'd like to retrieve information from an XML file, however the way it's formatted is pretty strange. Here it is...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Careers>
    <CareerList>
        <CareerName></CareerName>
        <CareerDescription></CareerDescription>
    </CareerList>
    <CareerList>
        <CareerName>Cook</CareerName>
        <CareerDescription>Cooks food for people</CareerDescription>
    </CareerList>
</Careers>
```

I'd like to get the 2nd value, which would be Cook and the description which is Cooks food for people, but instead I'm getting only the empty node. For example...

```
    public string CareerDescription(string CareerFile)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(CareerFile);
        string Description = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Careers/CareerList/CareerDescription").InnerText;
        return Description;
    }
```

How would I select the second node instead of the first?

Comment: have you tried changing ` string Description = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Careers/CareerList/CareerDescription").InnerText;` to something like this 
`string Description = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Careers/CareerList/@CareerDescription").value;` and you may go as far to check if not null then skip and or return the non null Description value

Comment: (http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?292473-Reading-Child-nodes-from-XML-file-C)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an index in your XPath expression:

```
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Careers/CareerList[2]/CareerDescription").InnerText
```

Personally I'd use LINQ to XML instead, mind you:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(CareerFile);
return doc.Root
          .Elements("CareerList")
          .ElementAt(1) // 0-based
          .Element("CareerDescription")
          .Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `SelectSingleNode` you should use `SelectNodes`: it will return `XmlNodeList nodeList`. Then you should take the `InnerText` of the element from that node list with index [1];

```
public string CareerDescription(string CareerFile)
{
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(CareerFile);
string Description = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("Careers/CareerList/CareerDescription")[1].InnerText;
return Description;
}
```

Refer to the documentation on this method on MSDN for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: The OP only actually wants to select a single node though - so he can index within the XPath expression. As I said in my answer though, I'd prefer to use LINQ to XML :)

Comment: That's fine! I've provided a bit more universal solution, just in case :-). Voted+ for your solution as well. Rgds, AB

Answer (score 0):

Just a straight way of LINQ to XML routine (and because it is LINQ, I prefer this way much more than the *"standard"* usage of XmlDocument with the support of XPath):

```
return XDocument.Load(CareerFile)
                .Descendants("CareerDescription").Skip(1).First().Value;
```