# Select specific node from XML document when there is two or more nodes with same name C#

Tags: c#, xml

Is there a way to select specific node of XML file when you have nodes with same name more then once?

For example I want to select the value of the node with name IBAN. But I have it twice as a child of some other two nodes.

I am getting node with name IBAN, put it gets first one of course.

```
public string GetIBANValueFromXML(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
{
    string ibanValue = "";
    XmlNodeList xnList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Element[@*]");

    if (xnList != null)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
        {
            XmlNode ibanNode = xn.SelectSingleNode("IBAN");
            if (ibanNode != null)
            {
                ibanValue = ibanNode.InnerText;
            }
        }
    }
    return ibanValue;
}
```

If there is a clean way to accomplish this? To use this functionality but to return second IBAN node value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value from node with same name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470157/get-value-from-node-with-same-name)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XPath `/Element/IBAN[2]` to select the second `IBAN` child element of the root element named `Element`:

```
XmlNode ibanNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Element/IBAN[2]");
if (ibanNode != null) { ... }
```